# Reading value from dynamic textbox

Tags: excel, vba

I've an excel vba form named as 'UserForm'. Overall, there's a button (name as 'buttonAdd') that the function could create/add textbox based on inputed (from 'a' variabel) value dynamically. Here's the code.

```
Public Sub buttonAdd_Click()
Dim a As Integer
a = TextBox1.Value
Dim cCntrl As Control

For i = 1 To a
    Set cCntrl = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "quarter", True)
    With cCntrl
        .Name = "quarter" & d
        .Width = 150
        .Height = 25
        .Top = 100 + (d * 25)
        .Left = 220
        .ZOrder (0)
    End With
 Next i
```

Now, I've a problem. I can't take/get the value from those dynamic textbox. I tried using this code for saving the value into 'A1' cell, but it's doesnt work.

```
Private Sub SaveButton_Click()
Dim a As Integer
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim cCntrl As Control
    Set Ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Ws.Range("A1").Value = quarter1.Value
End Sub
```

I thought the name of first dynamic textbox is quarter1, but when I tried to get the value, it didn't work. Is there anyway or hint for solving this issue. Just saying: just take the value of the first text box, write it there, then take another one and so on.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your problem is a simple typo. You have used `d` instead of `i` (`d` is undefined in your code). I recommend always using `Option Explicit`.

```
Public Sub buttonAdd_Click()
Dim a As Long ' Minor, but Integer I sjust too short these days for a lot of things.
Dim i as Long

a = TextBox1.Value
Dim cCntrl As Control

For i = 1 To a
    Set cCntrl = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "quarter", True)
    With cCntrl
        .Name = "quarter" & CStr(i)  ' explicit rather than implicit conversion
        .Width = 150
        .Height = 25
        .Top = 100 + (i * 25)
        .Left = 220
        .ZOrder (0)
    End With
 Next I
```

Edit: Might be a couple more typos in the `.Add` command (e.g. you might have wanted "quarter" & "1" instead of just "quarter"?) but I don't have the VBA reference up at the moment to check.

Comment: Thanks sir for repairing my typo. How about code for save/get the value from thoese dynamic textboxes? still didn't work

Comment: @FreeManI I got error when I used Option Explicit. It said: 'Invalid Inside Procedure'

What's wrong?

Comment: Put it at the top of your code module because, as the error says, it's invalid to put that inside a procedure (`Sub` or `Function`). In the VBE (code editor) go to `Tools | Options`, then the `Editor` tab, and check "Require Variable Declaration" to put it at the top of _every_ code module for you.

Comment: @FreeMan Thanks sir. I've check 'require variable declaration' in my editor tab. May I know, where I must put Option Explicit? Cause when I put it above Public Sub buttonAdd_Click(). It's still error. Actually, I don't get what is the function of Option Explicit. Could you mind to explain to me sir?

Comment: @FreeMan Thaaanks a looot Siir!